# How to add the an heart icon in xCode?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, tableview, accessoryview

My customtableview currently looks like this

[image]

I was wondering how to add a favourite icon like the heart in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you know how to drag & drop an UIImageView to the cell. After doing so, open the property inspector and set the image name to the name of the heart image (it would be 'heart' in case you have heart.png image included in Xcode project)